# Why does Windows Defender report “2 files scanned” when scanning a PDF I downloaded?

Tags: pdf

I downloaded a PDF eBook (link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2td5dy1menc0rar/Billiards%20A%20Genetic%20Introduction.pdf?dl=0)) and ran a quick scan using the Windows Defender. It reports:

- 0 threats found.
- Scan lasted 1 seconds.
- 2 files scanned.

However, it only scanned that one PDF file. Does this mean there is another file bundled to this PDF file? If yes, how to remove that file?

Comment: Seems like Windows Defender is well known for reporting incorrect file counts. So I would not sweat this since the most important line is:  “0 threats found.”

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your editing work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A bit of a stab in the dark but... Are you on Windows? Could be that some additional metadata for the PDF is saved and attached, al la https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-alternate-data-streams/

Comment: While you are well intentioned in this answer and the general idea of alternate data streams seems legit, the thing is this is an “answer” that is more of a comment and the link-only nature of the answer is really not accepted on this site as well. I would encourage you to earn up to 50 rep to leave comments such as this. You can earn rep by doing things such as editing posts in addition to posting well received questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I got the same result for several pdf files that I know they are safe.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN  the function on your PC THEN Take look in hidden folder options
Reset from default of Hide to Show

It may not be4 a false positive - Its often something other which might, eg, be malicious or spyware

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What function is this ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1188374)